# jQuery notifications plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, notifications

I am looking for jQuery Plugin that enabling me displaying notifications like Facebook or Google +.

When I googled it google returns some results that they mostly good for displaying alert or message to user but I want to display last system changes to user.

Comment: What kind of notifications are you trying to display and where will they be displayed. You might not even need jQuery. A Tad more details and I can help you out.

Answer (score 2):

I've made an open source jQuery notification system that can be integrated seamlessly with your web app, called [jNotifyOSD](http://vickychijwani.github.com/jquery-notify-osd/). You can see a demo on that link. The code's up on [GitHub](http://github.com/vickychijwani/jquery-notify-osd/). I've tried to keep the API clean and dead simple to use. Here's an example:

```
$.notify_osd.create({
  'text'        : 'Hi!',             // notification message
  'icon'        : 'images/icon.png', // icon path, 48x48
  'sticky'      : false,             // if true, timeout is ignored
  'timeout'     : 6,                 // disappears after 6 seconds
  'dismissable' : true               // can be dismissed manually
});
```

You can even set global defaults for all future notifications (can be overridden on a per-notification basis):

```
$.notify_osd.setup({
  'icon'        : 'images/default.png',
  'sticky'      : false,
  'timeout'     : 8
});
```

Also, I'm working on adding more features, so you could suggest some more features if you wish to use it :)

**UPDATE [13th Dec, 2012]**:

It's been some time, but I've finally implemented support for multiple visible notifications using a queue system. So for example:

```
$.notify_osd.setup({
  // ... config ...
  'visible_max' : 5                  // max 5 notifications visible simultaneously
  'spacing'     : 30                 // spacing between consecutive notifications
});
```

You can see a demo [here](http://vickychijwani.github.com/jquery-notify-osd/).

Comment: This would be a great plugin if you could have more than one notification at a time or set a sort of notification queue.

Comment: @ScottGreenfield I know it's been a _long_ time, but I finally got around to implementing a notification queue (actually: internally it's 2 queues - one for already visible notifications, another for "waiting" notifications). Check it out: http://vickychijwani.github.com/jquery-notify-osd/

Answer (score 0):

try this plugin: [Noty](http://needim.github.com/noty/)

have different implementations such as:

1. alert
2. success
3. error
4. warning
5. information
6. confirmation

And the notifications can be positioned at the:

1. top
2. topLeft
3. topCenter
4. topRight
5. center
6. centerLeft
7. centerRight
8. bottom
9. bottomLeft
10. bottomCenter
11. bottomRight

and you can put them in queue